# R lme4 1.1-7: REML=FALSE giving error "extra argument(s) ‘REML’ disregarded "

Tags: glmm, lme4-nlme

I'm trying to fit a model with the function `glmer` (`lmer4` 1.1-7 package) in R using REML but I just get an error saying `extra argument(s) ‘REML’ disregarded` (see below).
How else can I fit it with REML to optimize the random effects structure with this package?

```
a1<-glmer(Infected~(1|River),family=binomial,data=covertfrag,REML=FALSE)
Warning message:
extra argument(s) ‘REML’ disregarded
```

Answer (score 9):

Function `glmer` does not take argument `REML`, so the `glmer` call ignores it. The warning is telling you that is the case.

Function `glmer` always uses Maximum Likelihood (ML) rather than REstricted Maximum Likelihood (REML); see [the GLMM FAQ](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq#reml-glmm) for more detailed information. Only function `lmer` can take argument `REML`, and it must be a logical vector.

To check what arguments the function `glmer` can take, type `?glmer`. Or to see the whole function, type `glmer` without parenthesis and it will print to the console.

Comment: Thanks. But what other argument can I use with glmer to fit the model with REML since this one doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know what `REML` means. You should read the `lme4` documentation for an understanding of what options are available for its functions.

Comment: @lnes, `glmer()` always uses Maximum Likelihood (ML) rather than REstricted Maximum Likelihood (REML), see [here](http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq#reml-glmm).

Comment: If you're concerned about restricting the range of plausible parameter estimates in a hierarchical model, I would recommend using a package like stan.

Comment: Just a clarification: The function `lmer` *doesn't* have a `method` argument--this is in the `lme` function of the `nlme` package. The argument is `REML` (TRUE or FALSE) in function `lme4::lmer`.